# How to show a image preview of the files in IMCE file browser?

Tags: wysiwyg, files

I'm using the the [imce module](http://drupal.org/project/imce) with the [ckeditor module](http://drupal.org/project/ckeditor).

When you open the imce file browser to select/upload a image you can see a list of the images you have in your server.

This list shows the name for every image.

Is there a way to make this list to show a image preview of the image (a thumbnail)?

Look my capture:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have seen it work sometimes, but I can not tell does not always work. I will recommend you opening an issue on the IMCE module page in Drupal.org. See it working on the image below:

[image: IMCE showing images thumbnails]

Comment: It seems to work in some image files but not in all of them. In you capture I can see that the file: 13_b_0.gif is not showing the image preview at all. I created an issue for this module.

Comment: Did you figure it out, by any chance... I am having the same issue at the moment.. ?